# Some functions of Sony Camera Remote API seemed to be unavailable

Tags: clojure, camera, sony

## Background

I am currently working on a Clojure wrapper of Sony Remote Camera Control API Beta.

- API    : https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/
- Wrapper: https://github.com/hammartap/facet

## Symptom

Some functions, which getAvailableApiList function says "available" looks unavailable.
(Returns `IllegalArgumentException No matching field found` error.)

## Question

Am I missing API documentation?
If so, someone could guide me to the corresponding section of the document?
If not, I would like to know in which version these functions will be implimented.
Especially, I am interested in "(get|set)BeepMode", "(get|set)StillSize", setExposureMode, and so on.

I attached complete list of functions which looks unavailable for reference.[1]
Best.

---

#### Development environment

- OS

  - Mac OSX 10.7.5
- Language

  - Clojure 1.4.0 with Leiningen2
- Java

  - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
- Editor

  - Emacs 23.3

---

#### [1] Functions which seems to be  unavailable

"getMethodTypes",
"setSelfTimer",
"getSelfTimer",
"getSupportedSelfTimer",
"getAvailableSelfTimer",
"setPostviewImageSize",
"getPostviewImageSize",
"getSupportedPostviewImageSize",
"getAvailablePostviewImageSize",
"setExposureMode",
"getExposureMode",
"getSupportedExposureMode",
"getAvailableExposureMode",
"setBeepMode",
"getBeepMode",
"getSupportedBeepMode",
"getAvailableBeepMode",
"setCameraFunction",
"getCameraFunction",
"getSupportedCameraFunction",
"getAvailableCameraFunction",
"setStillSize",
"getStillSize",
"getSupportedStillSize",
"getAvailableStillSize",
"actFormatStorage",
"getStorageInformation",
"setTouchAFPosition",
"cancelTouchAFPosition",
"getTouchAFPosition",
"getSupportedExposureCompensation",
"getSupportedWhiteBalance",
"getVersions",

Comment: stacktrace + example of calling unavailable method is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Some undocumented API becomes avaliable after auth. You can see how it is done on QX100 here from line 144 to 151: https://github.com/Tsar/sony_qx_controller/blob/master/sony_qx_controller.py#L144

Answer (score 0):

You may not be using a camera that supports those features. Here is Sony's [capability chart](https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/)